# Synology SHR with 1 drive, soon to be 3

Tags: hard-drive, nas, synology

Kind of a weird question:

I just ordered a Synology DS918+ and 2 x WD RED 10TB for Amazon Prime Day (the purchase limit is 2), but the drives are out of stock and don't ship for over 2 weeks.

I eventually want to run 3 x WD RED 10TB.  Can I buy a single WD RED 10TB from another seller now, set it up as SHR, and add the 2 additional drives when I receive them?  Or do I need more than 1 drive to use SHR?

Answer (score 0):

For any RAID configuration requiring redundancy (when one drive fails), more than one drive has to be used. You are better off waiting for the other drives.